# How to run simple scripts using tortoise-orm?

Tags: tortoise-orm

How to run simple scripts that connect db and execute a query in [tortoise-orm](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a simple script, you can do this,

```
from tortoise import Tortoise

async def init():
    # Here we create a SQLite DB using file "db.sqlite3"
    #  also specify the app name of "models"
    #  which contain models from "app.models"
    await Tortoise.init(
        db_url='sqlite://db.sqlite3',
        modules={'models': ['app.models']}
    )
    # Generate the schema (run this only if you need to generate the schema)
    # await Tortoise.generate_schemas()

run_async(init())
```

`run_async` is a helper function to run simple async Tortoise scripts. If you are running Tortoise ORM as part of a service, please have a look at [The Importance of cleaning up](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#cleaningup) properly from tortoise orm docs.